# SQL: join 2 table and change id to username

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this:

table1:

```
id | item_name | entered_by | modify_by
1  | banana    |     2      |    1
2  | apple     |     4      |    3
3  | orance    |     1      |    1
4  | pineapple |     5      |    3
5  | grape     |     6      |    1
```

table2:

```
id | username 
1  | admin
2  | jack
3  | danny
4  | dummy
5  | john
6  | peter
```

how do i join these 2 table for table1's **entered_by** and **modify_by** is replaced by their username with id correspondingly on table2.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.item_name,
  t2enteredBy.username enteredBy,
  t2modifyBy.username modifyBy
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2enteredBy ON t1.entered_by = t2enteredBy.id
JOIN table2 t2modifyBy ON t1.modify_by = t2modifyBy.id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f284c/1).

In short, you need a join per each of those fields. That's why there is a double join on `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tmp.id, item_name, tmp.username as entered, b.username as modify
FROM (SELECT t.id, item_name, username, modify_by
    FROM table1 t
    INNER JOIN table2 a
    ON t.entered_by=a.id
)tmp
INNER JOIN table2 b ON tmp.modify_by=b.id
```